serve html-output from `GNU R`
On my (headless) development machine running Debian GNU/Linux (which I'm accessing via ssh) I'm having a purely CLI-based setup with neovim and Nvim-R as IDE for programming in GNU R. This works perfectly for programming and getting feedback via the R console output. In addition, for viewing plots I'm utilizing the httpgd-package and as a substitute for utils::View() I'm using visidata in combination with the rvisidata-plugin (which is sadly not on CRAN.
With this setup I'm quite content and can do almost everything that I could do with a graphical IDE (like e.g. [RStudio]. The only thing missing is the ability view (and, to be able to do that, also serve) html pages like the ones generated from htmlTable.
I'm aware that I can use packages like servr to serve static sites but this is not what I'm interested in - I'd like to have a tool which works interactively, similar to httpgd, but for html output.
Does something like that exist? If yes: how is this configured?
